# Vue update array state using the composition api

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to create some kind of state using the composition api in vue 3 with the following file:

```
// useNotifications.ts
const state = reactive<Array<Notification>>([]);

export function useNotifications() {
  return {
    state,
    add: (notification: Notification) => {
      state.push(notification);
    },
  };
}
```

This notification state is read and rendered in html from this the below:

```
// TheNotifications.vue
setup() {
    const notifications = useNotifications();

    let first = notifications.state[0];

    return {
      first,
    };
  },
```

And notifications are added at some form submit event like so:

```
// SomeForm.vue
notifications.add({ type: "success", text: "Food added" });
```

However, `TheNotifications` never sees the changes when pushing. I tried some different methods, for example with `toRef`, but I had no success. I'm new to this composition api thing and I was wondering what I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reactive` doesn't work with Arrays. Seems to be a limitation of the composition api. You can read a similar discussion [here](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/issues/219).

Use `ref` instead of `reactive`, it should work fine. I have built a few apps like this and can confirm it working.
So write: `const state = ref<Array<Notification>>([]);`, you will have it working. And as a rule of thumb, use `ref` for anything but objects, that's when you want to use `reactive`. It's more complex than that but if you use them like this, it will always work.